# Finding the top level Layerset in Photoshop using Javascript

Tags: javascript, scripting, photoshop

My current code is terrible, it's a Friday afternoon special:

```
if(layer.parent == doc && isLayerSet) {  
 //do something in this case fileNew.write('foo');  
}  
else if(layer.parent.parent == doc && isLayerSet) {  
 //do something in this case fileNew.write('foo');  
}  
else if(layer.parent.parent.parent == doc && isLayerSet) {  
 //do something in this case fileNew.write('foo');  
}  
else if(layer.parent.parent.parent.parent == doc && isLayerSet) {  
 //do something in this case fileNew.write('foo');  
}  
else if(layer.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent == doc && isLayerSet) {  
 //do something in this case fileNew.write('foo');  
}  
else if(layer.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent == doc && isLayerSet) 
{  
 //do something in this case fileNew.write('foo');  
}
```

I did this as a proof of concept to see if the rest of the script works (which it does).

The aim of the game for layer i want to get the name of it's top level parent (i.e. the first child of the document). all blocks should do the same thing.

I know there is an easier way of doing this however I'm still quite new at this and I'm not sure on some of the nuances of both javascript and photoshop so any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Are all of the blocks the same? `//do something in this case fileNew.write('foo');` ?

Comment: yes, sorry I failed to mention that. I'll amend it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something recursive. It can replace all "*if-else if*" statements.

```
(function getTopLayer(element) {
  if (element.parent == doc && isLayerSet) {
    //do something in this case fileNew.write('foo'); 
  } else {
    getTopLayer(element.parent);
  }
})(layer);
```

But please note that this will run infinitely, until first *if* is true.

Answer (score 1):

You might just use a loop to assign the current `parent` in the chain to a variable until the variable is equivalent to `doc`, or until the maximum number of allowed parents is reached:

```
function doTheThing(layer) {
  if (!isLayerSet) return;
  var currentLayer = layer;
  for (var parentCount = 0; parentCount < 6; parentCount++) {
    currentLayer = layer.parent;
    if (currentLayer === doc) {
      // do something
      // function call here for better readability
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works brilliantly however I do think @andrei-rosu answer fits what I want better. Thanks